Is there any form of Vajrayana Buddhism that is based on the Pali canon?
As far as I'm aware, most forms of Vajrayana Buddhism (which is really only Tibetan and Shingon I think) are based on the Mahayana (Chinese?) canon and accept their sutras generally.
Is there any form of Vajrayana which is based on the Pali canon?

In this question you wrote, "AFAIK Mahayana does not acknowledge the Pali Cannon and therefore the Dhammapada". That would be news to me: instead I thought that the canon was translated in Chinese, where it's called the Āgama and is accepted.

@ChrisW I'll read into it. I'm a total beginner, so I'm not quite sure what's what yet. Thanks for letting me know.

Yes I don't know either. But I got the impression from an answer like this one that the Agamas, such as they are, are a close translation (or in other words, the same). Yes there may be parts of the Pali canon that aren't part of the Chinese canon -- missing suttas, and differences in the Vinaya, I'd guess the Abhidhamma too; and Chinese sutras and commentary that aren't part of (and maybe that are later than) the Pali -- but still, "not acknowledge" or "not accept" might be misleading.

It isn't only Chinese. Nagarjuna is Indian. Wikipedia says his main work is, "detailed and careful analysis of most of the important discourses included in the Nikayas and the Agamas". And I don't even know what the original language of the Prajnaparamita was but that's a Sanskrit (not Chinese) name.
